# URL space replace cauese 20 added to the url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, preg-replace, space

My `codeigniter` controller name is like `asd ASd Aldsds 98Hsds`. I needed to replace the spaces with `-` symbol. For this I wrote

```
$news_title = $this->uri->segment(1);

    $news_title = strtolower($news_title);

    $url = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $news_title);
```

But the above line outputs `$url` as :
`asd%20asd%20aldsds%2098hsds`
How can I remove these `%20` from my url. Any why these appears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) before the preg_replace.

```
$news_title = urldecode($news_title);
```

Comment: Thanks M42..its working.I think it should be `urldecode` instead of `url_decode`.

Comment: @Nitish: Yes, you're rigth. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the ...->uri->... will do an URL Encoding. Urls must not have spaces. If you can't avoid them you need to convert them to %20 to make the url valid.